# How to make a digital clock dynamic?

Tags: javascript

This is my full code of month calender. It also show time on today's date. The gettime function return the current time, but the time is static. To make the time dynamic what should I do?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function gettime()
 {
  var time=new Date()
  var hour=time.getHours()
  var minute=time.getMinutes()
  var text=hour+':'+ minute
  return text
  }
function nameofmonth(month)
 {
   var monthname=new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December")
   return monthname[month]
   }
 function monthdays(month,year)
  {
    var daysofmonth=new Array(31,28,31,31,30,31,31,31,30,31,30,31)
     if(year%4==0)
       daysofmonth[1]=29  
         return daysofmonth[month]   
     }

 function table()
   {
     var now=new Date()
     var hour=now.getHours()
     var minute=now.getMinutes()
     var second=now.getSeconds()

     var date=now.getDate()
     var month=now.getMonth() 
     var year=now.getFullYear()
     now.setFullYear(year,month,1)
     var firstday=now.getDay()
     var monthname=nameofmonth(month)
     var daysofmonth=monthdays(month,year)
     if(firstday>0)
          var k=-(firstday-1)
     else
           k=1
      var table="<table border=5 cellspacing=9 cellpadding=13>"
      table +="<th colspan=7>"+monthname+" "+date+"th</th>"
      table +="<tr><th>sun</th><th>mon</th><th>tue</><th>wed</th><th>thu</th<th>fri</th><th>sat</th></tr>"
     for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
          table+="<tr>"
          for(var j=0;j<7;j++)
           {
             if(k<=daysofmonth && k>0)
               { if(k==date)
                  table+='<td bgcolor="aqua">'+k+'<br>'+gettime()+ '</td>'
                  else
                   table+='<td>'+k+'</td>'
               k=parseInt(k)

             } 
            else
               table+="<td></td>"
             k++
        }
      table+="</tr>"
      }
     table+="</table>"
    document.write(table)
      }      
</script>
</head>
<body onload="table()">
</body >
</html>
```

Comment: `year%4==0` is not sufficient to test if a year is a leap year.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: until 2100 they're safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `<div id='clock'></div>` to the document. In `table()` replace document.write with

```
 document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = table
```

Write a separate onload function, in this function use `setInterval` to call `table()` periodically.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question then you need this. First change your

```
table+='<td bgcolor="aqua">'+k+'<br>'+gettime()+ '</td>'
```

line to

```
    table+='<td id="myclock" bgcolor="aqua">'+k+'<br>'+gettime()+ '</td>'
```

and add another function

```
function refreshtime()
{
     var timeis=gettime();
     document.getElementById('myclock').innerHTML=timeis;
}
```

then change your `<body onload="table()">` to

```
<body onload='table();setInterval(refreshtime,500);'>
```

Hope this is what you want. This will update only your time.

Comment: It is just pretty bad coding style since it's like using `eval`. You can pass a function to it: `setInterval(refreshtime, 500);`

Comment: Or may be I can pass an anonymous function like setInterval(function(){...}, 500);, is that ok ?

Comment: Yes, but if you just call a single function in there and not pass any arguments you can just pass the function directly.